# Having trouble with JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

Where is the mistake in the code :/ I am so silly I can't find it.

```
// Draw chart
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>&mysqltablename=<?php echo $mysqltablename; ?>&datatabletyp=<?php echo $datatabletyp ?>',
    function(data) {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart
        ({
            chart: { renderTo: '<?php echo $tabname; ?>', zoomType: 'x',  type: 'line', width:800 },
            credits: { enabled: false   },
            plotOptions: {  series: { marker : { enabled: false, states: {  hover: { enabled: true  }  }   } }   },
            xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
            title: { text:' '     },
            yAxis: { title: { text: ''  } },
            legend: { enabled: false },
            series: [{ name: 'john', data: data[] }],
        });
        Highcharts.setOptions({ global: { useUTC: false } });
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2, '.', ',');
    });
});
```

Console throws this error

[image: Error]

Comment: Also remove the trailing comma. Not allowed in IE

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like `token }` although it should be `token ]`. Anyways, there are only two `]` in this line, it cannot be that hard to tinker with them ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have `data: data[]`

If you want to access an index of an array/property of an object in a variable called `data` then you have to specify the index or property name: `data: data[1]` / `data: data['foo']` / `data: data.foo`

If you want to pass the entire array or object, then you must not use the square brackets: `data: data`.

Comment: THATS THE SOLUTION! I LOVE YOU :) Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @Susanne92 Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. It helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
series: [{ name: 'john', data: data[] }]
```

The `data[]` part is wrong. Simply make it `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[]` after `data`, so that you pass the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

`data : data[]` should be:

1. `data : []` if you want a new array, or
2. specify an index `data : data[index]`, or
3. if you simply want to reference the array it
   should be `data : data`

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the `,` at the end.

Instead of

```
series: [{ name: 'john', data: data[] }],
```

use this:

```
series: [{ name: 'john', data: data[] }]
```